# How to output a time Indexed Dask dataframe to csv based on time intervals

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, dask

I have a time indexed dataframe that I and I want to output to multiple csv files based on 15 minute intervals, is there a way to do that in dask without relying on apply or map? The data source I'm using can either be all in one file or split up so the existing partitions will vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to handle this would be to use [`repartition`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.repartition) to repartition the data into 15 minute partitions, and then use [`to_csv`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.to_csv) to output to files (creates a file per partition).

Something like this should work:

`df.repartition(freq='15T').to_csv(...)`